# How to output the correct linked list when Inserting a node at a specific position in a singly linked list recursively?

Tags: java

I am trying to implement it recursively but it is not returning the correct linked list with all the correct nodes.

I tried printing the node out after the recursive call and that gave me the correct linked list in reverse order but for some reason when i return head that does not work.

```
public Node<E> insertNodeAtPosition(Node<E> head,E element,int position)
  {
     Node<E> node = new Node<E>(element,null);
         if(head==null){
           return node;
         }

        if(position==0)
        {
           Node<E> current = head;
           head = node;
           head.next = current;
        }  

       insertNodeAtPosition(head.next,element,position-1);


       return head;
     }
```

I expect the output to include the inserted node but it doesnt appear there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
public static <E> Node<E> insertNodeAtPosition(Node<E> head, E element, int position) {
    return insertNodeAtPosition(null, head, element, position);
}

private static <E> Node<E> insertNodeAtPosition(Node<E> prev, Node<E> head, E element, int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(element, null);

        if (prev != null) {
            prev.next = newNode;
        }

        newNode.next = head;

        return newNode;
    }

    return insertNodeAtPosition(head, head.next, element, position - 1);
}
```

Will return the newly-inserted node.

EDIT: without the additional method:

```
private static <E> Node<E> insertNodeAtPosition(Node<E> prev, Node<E> head, E element, int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(element, null);

        if (prev != null) {
            prev.next = newNode;
        }

        newNode.next = head;

        return newNode;
    }

    return insertNodeAtPosition(head, head.next, element, position - 1);
}
```

Comment: Why did you make this a helper function and add another parameter and how would I know to do this? and would it be possible without the extra parameter in the helper function?

Comment: 1) Made an assumption your nodes only know about the "next" one and not the "previous" one (common problem on SO). 2) You need to know the "prev" one because you need to set its next to the new head. 3) Edited to remove the "helper" function; you'll need to work out how to pass the prev (which might be null) in this case. 4) Step through the code in a debugger or add log statements to help you understand what's happening when - this is a trivial recursion.

Comment: What do you mean by SO?